# ChosenJs change default option dynamically

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-chosen

I have a select element

```
  <select class="form-control position" name="position">
  <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Pick A Position</option>  
<?php
  $option = 0; 
foreach ($jsonIterator as $key => $val) {
      if(is_array($val)) {
        $option++
 ?>
   <option value="<?  echo $option; ?>"><?  echo $key; ?></option>  
 <?php }}?>   
</select>
```

I have 3 buttons, they have value 1, 2 and 3 respectively

```
<button type='button' value='1' class='btn-primary pull-left apply'>Apply</button>
```

I have the following JS

```
<script>$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.position').chosen();
    $(".apply").click(function () {
        var id = $(this).val();
        $('html,body').animate({ 
          scrollTop: $("#contact").offset().top }, 'slow');
        $.ajax
            ({
                type: "POST",
                url: "contact.php",
                data: id,
                cache: false,
                success: function (html) {
                    $(".positon").val(id).trigger('chosen:updated');
                }
            });
          })
    });
```

When I click on a button, the default option of ChosenJs is not changing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update your option values,

**HTML**

```
<select class="form-control position" name="position">
  <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Pick A Position</option>  
<?php $option = 0; foreach($jsonIterator as $key => $val){ ?>
    <?php if(is_array($val)){ $option++; ?>
   <option value="<?= $option; ?>"><?= $key; ?></option>  
 <?php }}?>   
</select>
```

and pass the select value to ajax,

**jQuery**

```
$(function(){
    $('select[name="position"]').chosen();
    $(".apply").click(function () {
        var id = $(this).val();        
        $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: $("#contact").offset().top }, 'slow');      
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "contact.php",
            data: { id : id },
            cache: false,
            success: function (html){
                $('select[name="position"]').val(id).trigger("chosen:updated");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

demo : https://jsfiddle.net/03Lxkoaz/30/

Comment: same problem, could you please make a working example on jsfiddle?

Comment: @Lynob, i have updated the answer with demo, check now.

Comment: thank you, `datatype:text` worked for me on the jsfiddle